# Selenium: Select and iterate through direct <li> child elements of a <ul> parent using python?

Tags: python, selenium

This is the part of the website I want to scrape.

[image: This is the part of the website I want to scrape.]

This is my python selenium code:

```
className = "_29hl"
try:
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, className,))
    )

    print( search )      
    print( search[0] )   
    # the two print statement above print two different webElement objects
    # why is that?

    # I want to do something like this...
    lists = search.direct_children
    links = [ each.find_element_by_tag_name('a') for each in lists ]

    for link in links:
        link.click()
        # other codes...

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

When I select the `className` from the console, it returns a collection

[image]

So I select the first one, and it returns the `<ul>` and its `<li>` child elements I want to scrape

[image]

How can it be selected and iterate through `<li>` elements using python selenium?
My goal is to select the `<a>` inside each `<li>` and make a click on that

Comment: whats the issue with this , the code looks good ?

Comment: there is no selenium command or maybe I don't know yet, that gets the direct children of a webElement object. Also, when I run this program, and print `search` and `search[0]`, they are two different webElement object. What I want is to select the exact `<ul>`. and iterate its children ...but I dont know how

Answer (score 2):

presence_of_all_elements_located , finds and returns all the element that has the class as specified , so search is a list containing all elements that has the specified class. when you call search[0] it gets the first element from the list.

to get direct child of this element use below locator

```
lists = search[0].find_elements_by_xpath("./li")
```

or

```
 lists = search[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, "./li")
```

you can use xpath , . means current element which is the ul , and then '/' means direct child

**Full code**

```
className = "_29hl"
try:
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, className,))
    )

    print( search )      
    print( search[0] )   
    # the two print statement above print two different webElement objects
    # why is that?

    # I want to do something like this...
    lists = search[0].find_elements_by_xpath("./li")

    links = [ each.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') for each in lists ]

    for link in links:
        link.click()
        # other codes...

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: the `lists` is not iterable...How can we iterate it

Comment: i was using find element which returns only the first element that matches the criteria , i changed them to elements

Comment: thank you...but I how can I click that? for example....lists[0].click()

Comment: @Eric you already have for loop to find a tag and click it just replace the lists in your code that's it

Comment: each.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

Comment: Change each. Element , as elements

Comment: But when you click it might open new window and you cannot click remaining